# Building a non-maven project in VScode for Wildfly

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, wildfly-13

I am looking for a way to build a non-maven spring mvc project with web.xml, where I want to use VSCODE with wildfly 13.
My WebContent looks like this
[Web-inf needs to have a folder 'classes'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw1Td.png)

Instead of Web-Inf/classes , classes are being built [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PawrC.png)

My .classpath file is as follows:

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="Major/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="Major/src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk1.8.0_111">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core.server.runtime.runtimeTarget/WildFly 13.0 Runtime">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="Major/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Is there something I'm missing here? Instead of Major/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes, classes are being built in Major/build/classes.

Comment: Is there anything wrong when you run simple code in this project, you can try to run it and if no error shown, you project misses nothing and is able to go further development.